# How to insert the value-of-select name into the href link?

Tags: php, xslt

I would like to pass the name into the link so that when i clicked the button the name will passed in. Any suggestion for how to edit the button?

```
<xsl:for-each select="person">
      <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/>.</td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="contact"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="email"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="address"/></td>
          <td>
             <a href="updateMember.php?name=" class="btn-secondary">Update Member</a>
             <a href="deleteMember.php?name=" class="btn-danger">Delete Member</a>
          </td>
      </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: How is this related to PHP?

Comment: this xsl file is combined with xml file by XSLTTransformation which is php file. By running this xsl file the button will linked to the other php file

Comment: The question/issue doesn't seem to have anything to do with PHP though. You should only add tags that are relevant to the question at hand. The target on those buttons could be anything without changing the issue you face.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the name you output earlier with `<td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>` then using `a href="updateMember.php?name={$name}"` should do, although depending on your data you might need to escape the value of `name` in the URL, easily done in XPath/XSLT 3 with `{encode-for-uri($name)}`, I don't think XSLT/XPath 1.0 has a function for that, unless you call e.g. into PHP from XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{expression}` to include an Xpath expression in a string context.

Variables can be defined with `xsl:variable`.

[EXSLT](http://exslt.org/str/functions/encode-uri/index.html) can be used for advanced features. One of them is `str:encode-uri()`. You define the additional namespace on the `xsl:stylesheet` element and set it as an extension element prefix.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
  extension-element-prefixes="str">

  <xsl:template name="example">
    <xsl:for-each select="person">
      <xsl:variable name="encodedName" select="str:encode-uri(name)"/>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="updateMember.php?name={$encodedName}" class="btn-secondary">Update Member</a>
          <a href="deleteMember.php?name={$encodedName}" class="btn-danger">Delete Member</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```